Are we allowed to explicitly specialize inline static data member of a class template without specializing the class template itself
I wrote the following snippet that compiles with clang but gcc and msvc rejects it. Demo
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
//wrapper 
template<typename T>
struct Wrapper
{
    inline static T value{};
    
};

template<> int Wrapper<int>::value = 42;         //clang:OK, gcc:Nope, MSVC:Nope
template<> double Wrapper<double>::value = 3.14; //clang:OK, gcc:Nope, MSVC:Nope

int main()
{
    
}

GCC says:
<source>:11:30: error: duplicate initialization of 'Wrapper<int>::value'
   11 | template<> int Wrapper<int>::value = 42;
      |                              ^~~~~
<source>:12:36: error: duplicate initialization of 'Wrapper<double>::value'
   12 | template<> double Wrapper<double>::value = 3.14;
      |     

So which compiler is right here?
What is the workaround?

You can also create a constexpr initialization function template that will initialize your constant (and that you can specialize on type if needed).  Like this, https://godbolt.org/z/zabv3Y4dz. At least that works on all 3 compilers.

@Gene Nope that isn't the case. A definition is also a declaration.

@user12002570 - according to p13: "An explicit specialization of a static data member of a template or an explicit specialization of a static data member template is a definition if the declaration includes an initializer; otherwise, it is a declaration."

@Gene Yes, so template<> int Wrapper<int>::value = 42; is a definition as it is an explicit specialization of static data member of the class template.

@3CxEZiVlQ This is already mentined in the answer below. But note that this doesn't mean that we can't specialize inline static members.

@3CxEZiVlQ We can explicitly specialize inline members as well. See [temp.expl.spec] in the  answer.

An alternative to @PepijnKramer's workaround could be using an immediately invoked lambda: https://godbolt.org/z/41jsv48xx

The program is well-formed as per temp.expl.spec#15. First note that inline static T value{}; is a definition. Now, from [temp.expl.spec]:

A member or a member template of a class template may be explicitly specialized for a given implicit instantiation of the class template, even if the member or member template is defined in the class template definition.
An explicit specialization of a member or member template is specified using the syntax for explicit specialization.

(emphasis mine)
This means that even though there is a definition for the member value inside the class template, we're allowed to provide an explicit specialization for that member.
Thus gcc and msvc are wrong in giving a diagnostic.


What is the workaround?

There are multiple workaround for this.
Workaround 1
One way is to use the old way of out of class definition as shown below:
template<typename T>
struct Wrapper
{
     static T value;   //not used inline here for workaround
    
};
template<typename T> T Wrapper<T>::value{};  //out of class definition

template<> int Wrapper<int>::value = 42;   //gcc starts accepting now


int main()
{
}

Workaround 2
Another way is to use constexpr if and lambda as shown below:
template <typename T>
struct Wrapper {
    static inline T value = [] {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>) return 3.14;
        else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) return 42;
        else return T{};
    }();
};

Demo

Because "haters will be haters". I've +1ed just for that :)

@Super-intelligentShade I see. Thanks :)
